# How can do subscription between two SELECT set?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, intersect

```
SELECT field1
FROM tbl1
WHERE conditionsx

...?

SELECT field2
FROM tbl2
WHERE conditionsy
```

I Want return same below↓
What is superscription between two `SELECT` results.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`INTERSECT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound_select_statements) operator:

```
SELECT field1 FROM tbl1 WHERE conditionsx
INTERSECT
SELECT field2 FROM tbl2 WHERE conditionsy
```